# Create new dict from old dict with some fields in old dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python.

I want to create a new dict, that have some fields in the old dict. Is there any way I can do this in a concise way without using loop?

Example: I have:

```
a = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    ....
}
```

And I want to create new dict b:

```
b = {
    'a': 1,
    'c': 2,
    ... # other keys I want to get from dict a
}
```

Update:
I may mislead people so I updated the question so it can be more clearer.

Assume I had dict a with keys `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`, and, I want to create a new dict b with keys `['b', 'c', 'd']` and the value of these keys is from dict a.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack dict `a` into the new dict, per [PEP-448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/):

```
b = {**a, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Note that in order for the new values to override those of the same keys in `a`, you would have to specify them after unpacking `a`.

Excerpt from PEP-448:

> In dictionaries, later values will always override earlier ones:
>
> ```
> >>> {'x': 1, **{'x': 2}}
> {'x': 2}
>
> >>> {**{'x': 2}, 'x': 1}
> {'x': 1}
> ```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question, I updated the question to make my question clearer. Could you recheck the question? Thanks.

Comment: I see. In that case there is no concise way to produce what you want without some sort of an explicit loop or repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to copy the dict and then manually set the updated keys:

```py
b = copy(a)
b['a'] = 1
b['c'] = 2
```

(Make sure `copy` is appropriate here and you don't have to use a deep copy.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just write a simple function to do this? And pass `a` keys as arguments?

```
a = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4,
}

b = {}

def copy_from_dict_to_dict(a_arg: dict, b_arg: dict, *args: str):
    for arg in args:
        b_arg[arg] = a_arg[arg]
```

And just call a function:

```
copy_from_dict_to_dict(a, b, 'a', 'b', 'd')
```

Output:

```
b = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}

keys = ['a','c']

b = dict(zip(keys, itemgetter(*keys)(a)))

print(b)
```

Prints

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```